# How do I create an agent noun from volo?

Tags: verbs, noun, agent

I'd like to create an agent noun from the verb *volo* (*volare*), meaning "one who flies". For some additional context, this will be used as a name for an animal that flies but has characteristics that make it noteworthy that it flies. In other words, by calling the thing a "flyer" it is highlighting that skill in particular (as opposed to something like *avis* where flying is inherent to the animal).

It seems like using -or is common for agent nouns, but I'm unsure of which conjugation of *volo* to use with that.

Comment: Apparently there is a late Latin (“lat[ino] tardo”) form _volator_, -_oris_: https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/volatore/

Comment: It's perhaps worth pointing out that there are two verbs *volo*: *velle* (want) and *volare* (fly). This question only concerns the latter one, but I'd be happy to see a separate question on the former one, too.

Comment: I'd be curious to see that as well. I updated the question just to make it clearer which verb this is, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Additionally, you can just use the present participle: *volans, volantis*. Both Lucretius and Vergil use *volantes* to mean "birds." From L&S:

> 2. P. a. as subst.: vŏlantes , ĭum, comm., the birds (poet.), Lucr. 2, 1083; Verg. A. 6, 239; 6, 728.—

Answer (score 6):

It's not a standard agent noun formation, but there is in fact a word for "flier" or "flying one" derived from *volāre*: [***volucer -cris -cre***](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DV%3Aentry%20group%3D26%3Aentry%3Dvolucer). It was used both as an adjective and as a noun in the Classical period, though the noun generally took the feminine form (*volucris* rather than *volucer*).