# How do I create an agent noun from velle?

Tags: verbs, noun, irregular-words

In a previous question, I asked [how to make an agent noun from volo](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/18528/how-do-i-create-an-agent-noun-from-volo?noredirect=1#comment38939_18528), with the intended verb *volare*. In the comments, it was mentioned that *volo* is also a form of the irregular verb, *velle*.

Is there an existing agent noun for that verb, and if not, how would you make one from it?

Comment: Not worth repeating in an answer, but remember you can also use the present participle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two existing nouns with somewhat similar meaning are *[voluntarius](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/voluntarius)* and *[volo, volonis](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/volo)*, both of which have meanings that can be glossed as “volunteer”. Nouns formed with the suffixes *-arius* and *-o* sometimes have definitions approximating those of agent nouns.

As for a neologistic *-tor* noun built on *velle,* the future participle *voliturus* mentioned by L&S and the Medieval Latin abstract noun *[volitio](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/volitio)* make the form “volitor” seem the most likely.

As per [cmw♦'s comment](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/18536/how-do-i-create-an-agent-noun-from-velle#comment38949_18536), it's also a good idea to remember the present participle *volens*, which L&S explicitly says " = is qui vult, in the different meanings".